# change the values of the register writable fields while leaving the read only fields as they were

Tags: python

i was trying to write a code that change the values of the writable fields while leaving the read only fields as they were but the code is still not exactly doing what i am hoping for , could you help please ?
Bitno : bit position
Attr : register field attribute
Currval: reg filed current value
Newval : flipped value of reg field.

```
Bitno   Attr  Currval  Newval
17      ro     1         1
16      rw     1         0
15      rw     1         0
14      rw     1         0
13      ro     1         1
12      rw     0         1
11      rw     1         0
10      rw     1         0
9       rw     0         1
8       rw     0         1
7       ro     0         0
6       ro     0         0
5       ro     0         0
4       ro     0         0
3       ro     0         0
2       ro     0         0
1       ro     0         0
0       rw     0         1
Tot            0x3EC00   0x23301
```

the code written looks like this below :

```
def invert(register):
    """Flip writable bits."""
    flipped = 0
    for node in register.iter_nodes():
        print("reg.field current attribute", node.info['attribute'])
        val = node.read()
        #print("reg.field current val", str(val))
        if node.info["attribute"] == "rw":
            val ^= 2 ** node.info["numbits"] - 1
        flipped += val << node.info["lowerbit"]
    return flipped
```

the display output is this:

```
>>> reg_utils.invert(register)
reg.field current attribute ro
reg.field current attribute ro
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute ro
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute rw
reg.field current attribute ro
reg.field current attribute rw
0x37201
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a lot of bit flipping!
Much more than you meant.

You wrote

```
            val ^= 2 ** node.info["numbits"] - 1
```

but you intended

```
            val ^= 2 ** (node.info["numbits"] - 1)
```

Here is a simple demo of
[operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

```
>>> 2 ** 3 - 1
7
>>>
>>>
>>> 2 ** (3 - 1)
4
```

---

That node.info dict is a lovely data structure.
But you might find it convenient to summarize
all the "rw" bits into a single integer mask.
Then you could flip your favorite bits
with one XOR operation.